# Find the CDF of $X$ being the number of tosses of a fair dice until the numbers in each toss add to more than $6$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I recently ran into this problem on an assingment. Supose you have a fair dice and let $X$ be the random variable that counts how many tosses happen before the sum of the numbers that showed up in each toss adds up to something greater than $6$.

You're asked to find the CDF of $X$ which has support in $\{2,\dots,7\}$, but I can't figure out a closed form for it. I've tried calculating the probability function $\mathbb{P}[X=k]$ for each $k$ in the support of $X$ but it's a bit messy. Any ideas?

Comment: It won’t be nice. Your best bet is to just compute the 6 probabilities. If you were doing a bunch of rolls until the sum was greater than like 1000, then it’s possible to approximate the distribution fairly well after making some assumptions like normal distributions and how to turn that into number of die rolls, but the approximations/e algebra/complications don’t work well for small sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is working with the definition of CDF. We want to find the probability that the sum is greater than 6 in at $\textit{most}$ $x$ rolls. Now, consider $1 - P(X \leq x)$. This is the probability that the sum is greater than 6 in at $\textit{least}$ $x+1$ rolls. But this is equivalent to the probability that the sum is less than or equal to 6 in $\textit{exactly } x$ rolls. To calculate this new probability, we can sum across possible roll sums. The number of ways in which $k$ rolls can sum to $n \le 6$ = ${n-1 \choose k-1}$, so: $\displaystyle{P(X \leq x) = 1 - (1 - P(X  \leq x) = 1 - \sum_{i=x}^{6}{\frac{{i-1 \choose x-1}}{6^x}} = 1 - \frac{6 \choose x}{6^x}}$.

Note: if $x \geq 7$, then ${6 \choose x} = 0$, so the CDF becomes $1 - \frac{0}{6^x} = 1$.